# Detect how I run Python script

Tags: python, windows

How do I detect if a script is run from a Windows console or from Komodo debugger without passing different arguments to the script?

Comment: have you inspected sys.argv ?

Comment: @Sentinel: I would prefer not to use args to distinguish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I don't know Komodo, I don't think its standard input is interactive, so you could try

```
import sys
in_console = sys.__stdin__.isatty()
```

`in_console` will then be true if the invoker provides interactive `stdin` and you will get what you want, though not in an elegant way.